# Join CSV file to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r, csv, spatial-join, sp

I wanted to join a CSV file to a shapefile.

When I identified a field to facilitate the join, e.g.,

```
map <- spChFIDs(map, as.character(map$ID))
```

it returned

> Error in spChFIDs(SP, x) : lengths differ

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Thanks.  But the column ID does have unique values that can be used as the join field. Must the inputs of the field be of same length?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your map and csv?

Comment: @cengel  It's a huge datasets and a screenshot won't be enought to show the variations.  The field "ID" in the shapefile "map" is a string of numbers (with various number of digits).

Comment: Perhaps save the CSV to a table, so you know the join fields are the same data type.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you can do it in R using `sp::merge`

```
library(raster)
# read data    
p <- shapefile("path/file.shp")
d <- read.csv("path/file.csv")

# merge on common variable, here called 'key'
m <- merge(p, d, by='key')

# perhaps save as shapefile again
shapefile(m, "path/merged.shp")
```

Comment: Hi @RobertH, I was sent here from the question I posted yesterday. When I merge by the common variable, do I pull that variable from the shapefile or the CSV? The two variables are matching in content, but not by name. I've tried playing around with it a bit and keep getting errors (mainly: Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, , by.x, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected)

Comment: Figured it out. Because I needed to join the two layers that had different names, I had to alter the format a bit. It looked more like    merge(p, d, by.x = "key", by.y = "matching.key")

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do with R to join a shapefile with a csv. However, if this can help you, you can also do this on QGIS using the pluggin MMQGIS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried with ArcGIS before but the data set is huge and I prefer to do this in R.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in R then your shapefile and .csv need to be loaded as a data.frame or a data.table. You can use join() to merge them.

Do you have any more information about what kind of shapefile you have?

I've had luck doing the following when I merge shapefiles and data. Note that you need to leave off the .shp extension in the "layer" argument. I used "GEOID" where you'd put whatever the name of the "shape" in interest is.

```
library("rgdal")
library("data.table")
shapefile = readOGR(dsn = "DIRECTORY WITH SHAPEFILES", layer = "THE ACTUAL SHAPEFILE")
shapefile@data$id = rownames(shapefile@data)
shapefile.points = fortify(shapefile, region = "id")
shapefile.df = join(shapefile.points, shapefile@data, by = "id")
shapefile.df = subset(shapefile.df, select = c(long, lat, group, GEOID))
names(shapefile.df) = c("long", "lat", "group", "GEOID")
```

Then you can merge your data using something like

```
full.data = join(mydata, shapefile.df, by = "GEOID", type = "full")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in R then merging is actually not required. You can use ggplot to display your data on a map. See, my example. This one liner  works wonders with shape file `bangladesh = fortify(p1, region = "ADM1_EN")`. And, then you can use

```
ggplot() + geom_map(data = br2016a, aes(map_id = ADM1_EN, fill = HectareLocal), 
                    map =bangladesh) +
  expand_limits(x = bangladesh$long, y = bangladesh$lat) + 
  coord_fixed(.96) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="thistle2", high="darkred", 
                      guide="colorbar", na.value="white") +
  labs(title = "Bangladesh Boro Rice (Local variety), 2016", x = element_blank(), y = element_blank(), 
       fill='Hectares') +   theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

And, the map I get is here.

[image: Output]